# How to view data using junction table Yii2

Tags: yii2

I've got three tables

1. checkoutcounter {id, name}
2. user {id, username}
3. checkoutcounter_users { id, checkoutcounter_id, user_id}

I use gii and then add
in checkoutcounter model (I add and joinWith and find()->with but it still doesn't work):

```
public function getUser_display()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User_display::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
        ->viaTable(CheckoutcounterUsers::tableName(), ['checkoutcounter_id' => 'id']
        );
    }
```

In checkoutcounter model search:

```
 public function search($params)
    {
        $query = FinanceSettingsCheckoutcounter::find()->with('user_display');

        $query->joinWith('user_display');
    }
```

what should I add in checkoutcounter view to get usernames or user id's? Why when I add in gridview 'attribute'=>'user_display.id' it doesn't display any data?

```
echo yii\helpers\Json::encode($dataProvidercheckoutcounter);
```

shows

```
{"query":{"sql":null,"on":null,"joinWith":[[["user_display"],true,"LEFT JOIN"]],"select":null,"selectOption":null,"distinct":null,"from":null,"groupBy":null,"join":null,"having":null,"union":null,"params":[],"where":null,"limit":null,"offset":null,"orderBy":null,"indexBy":null,"modelClass":"app\\models\\FinanceSettingsCheckoutcounter","with":["user_display"],"asArray":null,"multiple":null,"primaryModel":null,"link":null,"via":null,"inverseOf":null},"key":null,"db":null,"id":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you're using your search() function, but you're not using $params.. And its not returning the results..

I belive the query should be like this:

```
public function search($params)
{
     $result = FinanceSettingsCheckoutcounter::find()->with('user_display')->all();
     echo yii\helpers\Json::encode($result);
}
```

if you are using this as part of a Search Model, returning a dataProvider, check out this link

http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2014/04/16/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview-yii2/